# Azure Search - Search Score

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am currently using Azure Search to perform product searches on my website.

I have the following indexes:

**A**: Index with 55,000 documents
**B**: Inde with 16 documents

All documents in index **B** were filled with index **A** documents

When performing a simple search in the 2 indices with the same parameters the results are not what I expect.

**Example**:

---

**Index A**:
**Query String**: search=kfc

Result sorted by search.score descending:
**ProductoName** - **search.score**
KFC Product1 -   1.6514521
KFC Product2 -   1.5482594

---

**Index B**:
**Query String**: search=kfc

Result sorted by search.score descending:
**ProductoName** - **search.score**
KFC Product2 -  0.21555252
KFC Product1 -  0.13616839

---

I am surprised the order of the results by search score changes, because they are exactly the same data only the amount of documents changes

The amount of documents affect in the assignment of search score ?, Could you indicate where I can read about it, I look in the documentation but I did not find anything about it

Could you explain to me why the order of the products is affected if it is the same information? :(

The Index has no Scoring Profile and is exactly the same information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is correct, scoring (and thus ranking) is indeed affected by the number of documents in the index. To compute scores we use some statistical characteristics of the data corpus, such as the frequency of each term across the entire corpus and within each document.

The article [How full text search works in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture) explains this in great detail. In particular, the section on [Scoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture#stage-4-scoring) goes into how frequencies (term frequency, document frequency) are used.

Comment: Hello Pablo , thanks for replying

I was reading the full Full Text Search article.

However I can not understand why the relevance is affected (in this case) by the number of documents in the index

because I would expect "KFC Product1" to remain more relevant both in index  **A** and index **B** independently
of the number of documents that exist in the index.

I understand that the search score is different but I think it should be maintained that:

**The search score of "KFC Product1" > "KFC Product2" Search score**

Comment: Another thought: very small indexes, such as the 16-doc index in your example, are sometimes impacted by how docs are internally sharded. Once you have enough documents stats tend to even out, but at small numbers you can see some corner cases come up. I wonder if this is one of these cases. Additionally, indexes go through compaction in the background, which consolidates stats and may also cause scores to change. Generally speaking we don't guarantee fully stable scores due to the statistical nature of the problem. That said, you should of course be able to explain why you get what you get :)